# scipy.stats attribute not found

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to `import scipy.stats as ss` but it keeps showing me an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\My Python Files\KNN_Classification.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 343, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 169, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What should I do?

Comment: How did you install Python and the `scipy` stack on Windows? This is important information (Anaconda? clean install of Python + pip install?)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a wrong installation. You should remove the build directory as well as the installed scipy in site-packages, and then reinstall scipy.